# image redirect Centered

Tags: html, css, visual-studio

I'm new and I cant align my social redirect images to be centered to the "contact me" header. Text align doesn't work and other solutions I found for my problems just puts it in order vertically.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <style>
        .feature {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .feature figure {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }
        .resize {
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 128px;
            height: 128px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    [HEADER]
    <h1>Contact Me!</h1>
    <section class="feature">
        <figure>
            <a href="url">
                <img class="resize" src="images/discord.png" alt="Discord"></a>
            <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <a href="url">
                <img class="resize" src="images/insta.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
            <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The later tags don't have any idea how wide the "Contact Me! text is.  The `<h1>` tag spans the entire width.  You would be better off using `margin-left` to get your images to line up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play around with the margins in `.feature figure`. I changed the size of the images and added a border to them so i could see what was going on.

```css
.feature {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.feature figure {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 8px;
}

.resize {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
[HEADER]
<h1>Contact Me!</h1>
<section class="feature">
  <figure>
    <a href="url">
      <img class="resize" src="images/discord.png" alt="Discord"></a>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <a href="url">
      <img class="resize" src="images/insta.png" alt="Instagram"></a>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: followed the answer, but turns out if you add a background to .feature, you can see that it only shows part of the page. adding "width: 100%;" to .feature will expand to the whole page and centering in the middle of the page.

Comment: Start a new question. Include details about the 'background'. Tnx

Comment: I think I know what you mean. Try removing `text-align: center;`.